# mixed_dml on batch execution on unknown standard object

Tags: apex, custom-object, batch, dml, standard-objects

I'm running a batch that updates several custom objects. Sometimes I get a mixed_dml error but it's not something I can reproduce, It's an intermittent error. The message that is thrown is:

> MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): myCustomObject__c, original object: CustomExperience: [].

What is this `CustomExperience` object? I'm not directly using it and had no idea it existed.

Comment: Very interesting...can you add your code?

Comment: Find out the Trigger which is updating a setup object based on custom object fields. Not all that custom object records are same. Find out that record.

Comment: Interestingly, CustomExperience doesn't show up in my key scanner, either, although I suppose it might be a newer object and I Just need to update my API version.

Comment: Is your org in Spring 17 by any chance?

Comment: You should definitely open up a case with support for this one if you are able to and haven't already.

Comment: I have seen this happen for example when updating the product2 which caused the opportunity to be updated and a rollup on the account was also updated. No triggers on account. May not make sense but I have seen it happen before just do not recall exact details other than product2 was first object and only update was a rollup on account (no dml). No idea what CustomExperience is

Comment: hmm `CustomExperience` isn't in the V39.0 Preview SFDC Objects Guide either